# How to reference Html.TextBoxFor value in Controller action (updating a table in asp.net-mvc)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a sales web application. I want to update the quantity left in stock after a sales is input. I set an id for the textbox, and am using the textbox id inside the query. I believe am doing it wrongly.

Please see my View and Model codes below. (I am open to other ways on how to do this).

My View code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:40%; margin-top:2%">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSales", "Sales", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Prod_id, ViewBag.SalesName as        SelectList, "--Select Product--", new { id = "ProdIds", @class = "form-control"        })
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Unit_purchase, new { id = "quant", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Amount Purchase" })
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Unit_price, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unit Price" })
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Emp_id, ViewBag.EmpName as SelectList, "--select Employee--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    //@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Dates, new{@placeholder = "Date", @type = "date", @Value = Model.Dates.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dates, new { @type = "date" })
    <br />
    <br />

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cust_id, ViewBag.CustName as SelectList, "--Select Customer--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <input type="Submit" value=" Submit" />  <input type="reset" value=" Reset" />
}
 </div>
```

My Controller Code (updating query code start at ---- using(SqlConnection……)

```cs
    namespace Salesapp.Controllers
     {
     public class SalesController : Controller
      {
        // GET: Sales
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SalesIndex()
        {
            SalesLayanEntities3 db = new SalesLayanEntities3();
            List<Product> list = db.Products.ToList();
            ViewBag.SalesName = new SelectList(list, "prod_id", "prod_name");

            List<Employee> listi = db.Employees.ToList();
            ViewBag.EmpName = new SelectList(listi, "emp_id", "emp_name");


            List<Customer> listiw = db.Customers.ToList();
            ViewBag.CustName = new SelectList(listiw, "cust_id", "cust_name");

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SaveSales(SalesForm model)
        {
            try
            {
                SalesLayanEntities3 db = new SalesLayanEntities3();
                Sales_Record sale_prod = new Sales_Record();

                sale_prod.unit_price = model.Unit_purchase;
                sale_prod.unit_purchase = model.Unit_price;
                sale_prod.prod_id = model.Prod_id;
                sale_prod.emp_id = model.Emp_id;
                sale_prod.Dates = model.Dates;
                sale_prod.cust_id = model.Cust_id;

                db.Sales_Record.Add(sale_prod);
                db.SaveChanges();
                int latestProdId = sale_prod.sales_id;
                TempData["status"] = "Success";

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=SalesLayan;User ID=username;Password=mypassword;"))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd12 = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
                    cmd12.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd12.CommandText = "update product set prod_quantity=prod_quantity-" + quant.Text "where prod_id=" + ProdIds.Text;
                    cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;


            }
            return RedirectToAction("SalesIndex");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, it makes little sense writing a question title and logic around business detail. I mean who is going to click on this title and go OH i know how to `remove product sold from the product stock` Questions and titles should be framed in the technology you are using, ie query to remove child table from parent, ect ect ect ect ect ect ect

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Am new to c# and asp.net. Am just doing this for fun. Please is there anyway you think I can improve code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you may have an incorrect variable reference for the quantity to be deducted from the stock.

```
cmd12.CommandText = "update product set prod_quantity=prod_quantity-" + quant.Text "where prod_id=" + ProdIds.Text;
```

On the line above `quant.Text` may be an incorrect variable reference.

`quant.Text` may need to be `sale_prod.unit_price` or `model.Unit_purchase`

Your sql command is setting the `prod_quantity = prod_quantity - quant.Text`.

However there is no variable `quant.Text` in the `SaveSales` method.

When using the Helper TextBoxFor it uses the model name as the input field name:

Example: TextBoxFor() in Razor View

```cs
@model Student

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Html Result:

```html
<input class="form-control" 
        id="StudentName" 
        name="StudentName" 
        type="text" 
        value="John" />
```

> TextBoxFor
>
> TextBoxFor helper method is a strongly typed extension method. It generates a text input element for the model property specified using a lambda expression. TextBoxFor method binds a specified model object property to input text. So it automatically displays a value of the model property in a textbox and visa-versa.

Reference:

- [Create TextBox using HtmlHelper in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-textbox-textboxfor)

When the form is posted back .NET MVC composes the form values into the Action parameter type using what is called Model Binding:

> ASP.NET MVC model binding allows you to map HTTP request data with a model. It is the process of creating .NET objects using the data sent by the browser in an HTTP request. The ASP.NET Web Forms developers who are new to ASP.Net MVC are mostly confused how the values from View get converted to the Model class when it reaches the Action method of the Controller class, so this conversion is done by the Model binder.

Reference

- [ASP.NET MVC - Model Binding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_model_binding.htm)

In relation to [Joel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) comment, it would be best practice when passing parameters to an sql statement to use SqlParameters, as in the example below:

> ```cs
> // 1. declare command object with parameter
>   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
>       "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);
> ```

Using parameterized sql commands would help to prevent sql injection attacks. A good practice would also be to filter and validate your user input, since you are using it in your sql update command.

### References

- [preparing a SqlCommand Object for Parameters](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)

Comment: "qant" is a TextBox id in the View. The Textbox is where the quantity sold is input when sales are made. So am subtracting the value inputed form the prod_quantity in the database.

Comment: The `SaveSales(SalesForm model)` parameter should contain the reference to the input field so use something like `model.quant.Text`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @stormwild. The variable is still not recognized. This is the declaration in View --- `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Unit_purchase, new { id = "quant", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Amount Purchase" }) <br />`

Comment: Sorry when the quant field is posted back it would be referenced as `model.Unit_purchase` in your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I also thought of that. But am not sure how to write an update query with the "model.Unit_purchase" to deduct the prod_quantity from the database. I will appreciate if you can kindly help me with this or please just provide hint. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @Joel's answer actually helps you with that in a secure way, in your Controller Action the SaveSales(SalesForm model) the model parameter is populated with the values entered by the user. You can use this model object and reference the `model.Unit_purchase` property and pass that to your parameterized sql query as shown in Joel's answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this section:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=SalesLayan;User ID=username;Password=mypassword;"))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd12 = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
    cmd12.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd12.CommandText = "update product set prod_quantity=prod_quantity-" + quant.Text "where prod_id=" + ProdIds.Text;
    cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Do it like this instead to avoid sql injection issues and improve performance:

```
string sql = "update product set prod_quantity=prod_quantity- @sold_quantity where prod_id= @Prod_ID";
using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=SalesLayan;User ID=username;Password=mypassword;"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon))
{
    //Have to guess at types and lengths here. Use actual types and lengths from the database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sold_quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(quant.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prod_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(ProdIds.Text);
    sqlCon.Open();
    cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Joel. But for some reason it states that quant.Text is not defined. I already set the textbox id in the view --- `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Unit_purchase, new { id = "quant", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Amount Purchase" })
    <br />`

Comment: Use the `model.Unit_purchase` value instead of `quant.Text`. Same for `ProdIds`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works perfectly